# ajax highchart. how to passing data to highchart?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, highcharts

this is my query on my controller. I want to register participants every year. I got the year and the data every year. but i dont know how to passing my data in highchart dynamically

```
if ($request->ajax()) {

        $tahun = Peserta::orderBy('tanggal','asc')->select(\DB::raw("YEAR(tanggal) as year"))->distinct()->get();
        $years = $tahun->pluck('year');
        $value_an_year = [];
        $month = [01,02,03,04,05,06,07,8,9,10,11,12];
        $monthNames = collect($month)->transform(function ($value) {
            return \Carbon\Carbon::parse(date('Y').'-'.$value.'-01')->format('M');
        })->toArray();

        $cetak_bulanan = [];
        foreach($years as $key => $thn){
            $value_an_year[] = Peserta::where(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(tanggal, '%Y')"),$thn)->count();
            
            $bulanan = [];
            foreach($month as $key => $bln){
                $bulanan[] = Peserta::where(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(tanggal, '%Y')"),$thn)->where(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(tanggal, '%m')"),$bln)->count();
            }
            $cetak_bulanan[] = implode(',',$bulanan);
        }

        $hasil_bulanan = implode('<br>',$cetak_bulanan);
        $hasil_tahunan = implode(',',$value_an_year);
        $nama_bulan = implode(',',$monthNames);

        return response()->json(
            [
                'status'    => 200,
                'tahunan'   => $value_an_year,
                'tahun'     => $years,
                'message'   => 'chart perkembangan pengguna tilawati'
            ]
        );
    }
```

this is the highchart javascript

```
$.ajax({
            url: '{{ route("chart.perkembangan.pengguna") }}',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response.tahunan, '-' ,response.tahun);
                Highcharts.chart('container3', {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    title: {
                        align: 'left',
                        text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2018'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        align: 'left',
                        text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://statcounter.com" target="_blank">statcounter.com</a>'
                    },
                    accessibility: {
                        announceNewData: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'category'
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Total percent market share'
                        }

                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            borderWidth: 0,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
                    },
                    
                    series: [
                        {
                            name: "Tahunan",
                            colorByPoint: true,

                            data: [
                                {
                                    name: "Firefox",
                                    y: 10.57,
                                    drilldown: "Firefox"
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "Internet Explorer",
                                    y: 7.23,
                                    drilldown: "Internet Explorer"
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "Safari",
                                    y: 5.58,
                                    drilldown: "Safari"
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "Edge",
                                    y: 4.02,
                                    drilldown: "Edge"
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "Opera",
                                    y: 1.92,
                                    drilldown: "Opera"
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "Other",
                                    y: 7.62,
                                    drilldown: null
                                }
                            ],
                        }
                    ],

                    drilldown: {
                        breadcrumbs: {
                            position: {
                                align: 'right'
                            }
                        },
                        series: [
                            {
                                name: "Chrome",
                                id: "Chrome",
                                data: [
                                    [
                                        "v65.0",
                                        0.1
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v64.0",
                                        1.3
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v63.0",
                                        53.02
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v62.0",
                                        1.4
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v61.0",
                                        0.88
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v60.0",
                                        0.56
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v59.0",
                                        0.45
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v58.0",
                                        0.49
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v57.0",
                                        0.32
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v56.0",
                                        0.29
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v55.0",
                                        0.79
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v54.0",
                                        0.18
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v51.0",
                                        0.13
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v49.0",
                                        2.16
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v48.0",
                                        0.13
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v47.0",
                                        0.11
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v43.0",
                                        0.17
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v29.0",
                                        0.26
                                    ]
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Firefox",
                                id: "Firefox",
                                data: [
                                    [
                                        "v58.0",
                                        1.02
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v57.0",
                                        7.36
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v56.0",
                                        0.35
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v55.0",
                                        0.11
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v54.0",
                                        0.1
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v52.0",
                                        0.95
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v51.0",
                                        0.15
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v50.0",
                                        0.1
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v48.0",
                                        0.31
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v47.0",
                                        0.12
                                    ]
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Internet Explorer",
                                id: "Internet Explorer",
                                data: [
                                    [
                                        "v11.0",
                                        6.2
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v10.0",
                                        0.29
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v9.0",
                                        0.27
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v8.0",
                                        0.47
                                    ]
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Safari",
                                id: "Safari",
                                data: [
                                    [
                                        "v11.0",
                                        3.39
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v10.1",
                                        0.96
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v10.0",
                                        0.36
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v9.1",
                                        0.54
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v9.0",
                                        0.13
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v5.1",
                                        0.2
                                    ]
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Edge",
                                id: "Edge",
                                data: [
                                    [
                                        "v16",
                                        2.6
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v15",
                                        0.92
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v14",
                                        0.4
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v13",
                                        0.1
                                    ]
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Opera",
                                id: "Opera",
                                data: [
                                    [
                                        "v50.0",
                                        0.96
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v49.0",
                                        0.82
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "v12.1",
                                        0.14
                                    ]
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

My Question is
how do I get the "data name" in my series to be filled with "tahun" and "data y" to be filled with "tahunan"

[image: my response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array and response json in your controller and each loop in your front js.

**Controller:**

```
$data['chart'] = array([
                'status'    => 200,
                'tahunan'   => $value_an_year,
                'tahun'     => $years,
                'message'   => 'chart perkembangan pengguna tilawati'
]);
return response()->json($data);
```

**JS:**

```
success: function(response) {
$.each(response.chart, function (key, value) { 
let tahun = value.tahun;
let tahunan = value.tahunan;
```

use tahun and tahunan and other variables further in your js code or append it to html for example:

```
$("#div id").append('<span>' + tahun + '</span>');
```

or

```
$("#div id").html('<span>' + tahun + '</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adapt your data structure to the format required by Highcharts - an array of objects or an array of arrays with 2 values. For example:

```
const mockedResponse = [{
    tahunan: 2015,
    tahun: 1
}, {
    tahunan: 2017,
    tahun: 86
}, {
    tahunan: 2019,
    tahun: 64
}, {
    tahunan: 2020,
    tahun: 52
}, {
    tahunan: 2021,
    tahun: 4514
}, {
    tahunan: 2022,
    tahun: 8881
}];
const processedData = response.map(dataEl => [dataEl.tahunan, dataEl.tahun]);

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: processedData
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s58w3tdy/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data